# Controls disappearing when embedding table in container view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with one prototype cell. If I add a label to this for example, it is visible when the app runs. If I then embed this table view into a container view, the cells are still visible, but the label disappears. Is this a (known) bug?

Answer (score 1):

When you add it to the container view, you may be getting a request for the tableCell again, and that may be where your issue is. Add log messages to your dataSource delegate and delegate methods and see what the table is doing.

I move views around all the time, have tableViews in container views, it all works fine. Also make sure you have a strong reference to the tableView while it moves so that it does not get dalloced then re-created. With log messages you should be able to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Im not too sure where I would place these log messages though, as I have not added any code. Could it be placed in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I placed an NSLog in ViewDidLoad, and this is called twice. How would I go about getting my controls back?

Comment: You said the label disappears - so after you moved the table (and logged that), did you get another request for the cell? I'm going to guess the tableView will reload the table when the superView changes or goes nil then gets set again. So I imagine you are getting a flurry of data/delegate messages, you need to look at them and figure out what's going on. I'm trying to give you a way to find your problem, as I (obviously) don't know it myself.

Comment: Thats fair enough. I'm using storyboard to add the tableView to a container, how do I log it 'moving?' it's already there?

Comment: This is where I sign off - sorry don't use storyboards. In the traditional app, you would do this in code and thus it would be easy to track.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show me how to do it in code?

Comment: Create a simple one-view project in Xcode (not using Storyboards), do the operations you want by say adding one button that moves the table, make the table take the lower part of the view (say 302x100), the table has one cell, then get this project to demonstrate your problem. Once you get the problem to show itself, then post the project to Dropbox or similar, then I or others can look at it (and update your Question to show where the project is). If I write the code to do it, and it works, you'll look at it and say "Well, that's not how I'm doing it" and it won't help anyone.

Comment: When you say don't use storyboards, does that mean NIBs too?

Comment: No, of course not. Just go into Xcode, New Project, unselect Storyboards. I just don't use them (nor do most of the older developers) - and if you checked that I wouldn't know how to proceed. The simple one view project Xcode generates is going to be one UIViewController with nib.